# TypeError("Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. " K.learning_phase(): 0

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, keras

I am porting a Keras, Tensorflow, and OpenCV script to TF2 and Keras 2 and have run into a problem. I am getting an error on K.learning_phase(): 0. 
The error happens in this code section.

```
ef detect_image(self, image):
        if self.model_image_size != (None, None):
            assert self.model_image_size[0]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
            assert self.model_image_size[1]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
            boxed_image = image_preporcess(np.copy(image), tuple(reversed(self.model_image_size)))
            image_data = boxed_image

        out_boxes, out_scores, out_classes = self.sess.run(
            [self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes],
            feed_dict={
                self.yolo_model.input: image_data,
                self.input_image_shape: [image.shape[0], image.shape[1]],
                tf.keras.learning_phase(): 0  })
```

here is a gist to the full code
https://gist.github.com/robisen1/31976de17af9e752c6ba8d1dd0e08906

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcam_detect.py", line 188, in <module>
    r_image, ObjectsList = yolo.detect_image(frame)
  File "webcam_detect.py", line 110, in detect_image
    K.learning_phase(): 0
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\simplecv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 705, in __hash__
    raise TypeError("Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. "
TypeError: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.
(simplecv) PS C:\dev\lacv\yolov3\yolov3ct>
```

I am not sure what is going on. I would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use Tensorflow 1.x, which works in graph mode whereas TensorFlow 2.x works in eager mode. TensorFlow 1.X requires users to manually stitch together an abstract syntax tree (the graph) by making tf.* API calls. It then requires users to manually compile the abstract syntax tree by passing a set of output tensors and input tensors to a session.run() call. TensorFlow 2.0 executes eagerly (like Python normally does) and in 2.0, graphs and sessions should feel like implementation details.

The error is due to version. If you are using session in TF2 then you need to use the compatible version and same goes with other operations. Also in TF2 it is [tf.keras.backend.learning_phase](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/learning_phase).

Would recommend to go through the guide - [Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).

For Example Below Code throws the error similar to the error you are facing -

```
import tensorflow as tf 
print(tf.__version__)
x = tf.constant(5) 
y = tf.constant(10) 
z = tf.constant(20) 

# This will show same error. 
tensor_set = {x, y, z} 
tensor_dict = {x: 'five', y: 'ten', z: 'twenty'}
```

Output -

```
2.2.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-509b2d8d7ab1> in <module>()
      6 
      7 # This will show same error.
----> 8 tensor_set = {x, y, z}
      9 tensor_dict = {x: 'five', y: 'ten', z: 'twenty'}
     10 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __hash__(self)
    724     if (Tensor._USE_EQUALITY and executing_eagerly_outside_functions() and
    725         (g is None or g.building_function)):
--> 726       raise TypeError("Tensor is unhashable. "
    727                       "Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.")
    728     else:

TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.
```

But below code will fix the issue -

```
import tensorflow as tf 
print(tf.__version__)
x = tf.constant(5) 
y = tf.constant(10) 
z = tf.constant(20) 

#This solves the issue 
tensor_set = {x.experimental_ref(), y.experimental_ref(), z.experimental_ref()} 
tensor_dict = {x.experimental_ref(): 'five', y.experimental_ref(): 'ten', z.experimental_ref(): 'twenty'}
```

Output -

```
2.2.0
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-4-05e379e669d9>:12: Tensor.experimental_ref (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use ref() instead.
```

If you are still facing the error, then kindly share the reproducible code for the error like above. Will be happy to help you.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Robi Sen - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: The link to tf.keras.backend.learning_phase is broken, like so many others on tensorflow.org/guide! Still, +1 for some good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

try to disable tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import disable_eager_execution

disable_eager_execution()
```